# Fancybox iFrame request being cancelled

Tags: jquery, fancybox, frontend

All,

I'm half embarrassed to ask this, but can anyone help me figure out why the video isn't rendering when you click on the featured video [here](http://infirmaryhealth.mdidev.com/home)?

Inspector just tells of the request getting cancelled, I can't find any more information than that. I've used fancybox a hundred times before with no problem. Maybe I've slipped somewhere in my setup code, but I've double and triple checked it now and can't seem to find any issues.

Thanks for any assistance-

---

**EDIT #1**

The plot thickens. I threw the `<a>` that should call fancybox and the YT video on Featured Video around the Media Center image and *it works there*. It was a copy and paste. Now I'm really scratching my head!

Comment: BTW : you are loading jQuery twice when you only need a single instance (ideally the latest version). Also, some of your scripts are outdated and cannot work with jQuery v1.9+ (some methods were deprecated like `$.browser` for instance) You should either update your scripts or rollback to jQuery v1.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized fancybox for this selector  :

```
$('.featured-video').fancybox({
   type : 'iframe'
});
```

but in this part of your html code :

```
<div class='featured-video'>
    <h3 class="blocked">Featured Video</h3>
    <div class="gray-box">
        <a class="fancybox.iframe featured-video" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fdn3ZTiFNaM" data-fancybox-href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/fdn3ZTiFNaM"><img src="sites/all/themes/blithely/assets/images/placeholders/featured-video.jpg" /></a>
        <p><a href="#">Family birthing center tour</a></p>
    </div><!--/graybox-->
</div><!--/featured-video-->
```

your `<div>` has the **same class** (`.featured-video`) as your anchor. Fancybox is trying to get the content from the first selector (the `<div>`), which doesn't provide any `href` hence the message

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.
```

Remove or rename the class of the parent container.

Comment: oh man. i feel pretty stupid now, ha. thanks for pointing out what should've been obvious!